# ARM Templates uniqueString per deployment

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I need to generate a unique hash in my ARM template for each azure virtual machines I create. I currently deploy all virtual machines inside the same resource group as I am using a shared image. This causes me a problem as I currently haven't found any way to generate unique name hashes for each deployment within a resource group.

I currently use this to generate my unique name but this only works inbetween resource groups. `"unique_string": "[uniqueString(resourceGroup().id]",`

Is there a way to do this per deployed instance?

Answer (score 1):

Well, generally it depends on how you deploy those. But you can use `copyindex` function ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions#copyindex)).
You could use something like `[uniqueString(resourceGroup().id, variables('vm1Name'))]` or `[uniqueString(deployment().name, parameters('vm1Name'))]` (so it is unique for every deployment you create.

Comment: What I really need is a fully automatic way to do this inbetween deployments. I reasearched the copyIndex function and from what I understand it can only be used during "one" deployment to step an index if you have several resources you need to deploy with different indexes. This does not support my usecase however. A Date or Time function would be the optimal thing but I have found no such thing.

Comment: date-time is not available, you can vote for it on the feedback portal. also whats wrong with deploymentname + something. It should be unique for every deployment.

Comment: I would prefer to have a quick and simple deployment. Where I don't have to check that the name is unique every time. Deployment.name() is unfortunatley not unique.

Comment: what prevents you from creating a unique deployment name everytime you start a deployment. you should have it automated anyway. create a random alphanumeric string each time.

Comment: The whole reason for this question is that I would like to know if I can do it in an automated way. Yes I can make a random string everytime and It wont be readable at all but will work. I have previously had trouble with the random string clashing with one of the many things I deploy and I don't want that to happen again as it was a mess to clean up. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: well, are you passing parameters to the template? do they differ?

Answer (score 0):

I put datetime into tags and use tag for param of uniqueString

```
"uri": "[replace(parameters('prebuiltvms')[copyIndex()]['osDiskVhdUri'],'{unique}',uniqueString(parameters('prebuiltvms')[copyIndex()].tags.deploymentDate))]"
```